# How to price Barrier Options in Matlab

Tags: matlab, financial

When pricing a regular vanilla call/put option one can use the build-in function **blsprice**. It is known that there are also analytic formulae for barrier options (see http://www3.imperial.ac.uk/pls/portallive/docs/1/55071696.PDF page 16, ff). It would obviously not be ideal to copy these formulae into Matlab (it would be easy to make mistakes, etc). So I am wondering, does Matlab provide a function that has these formulae already implemented? I have found **instbarrier** but I am not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I have not yet managed to find any use of `instbarrier`. Also, Matlab does not currently have analytic formulae for barrier options implemented. It might do so in future releases.

In the meantime, you will have to price barriers via trees:

```
Sigma           = 0.1;
AssetPrice      = 100;
OptSpec         = 'call';
Strike          = 105;
Settle          = '01-Jan-2003';
ExerciseDates   = '01-jan-2007';
BarrierSpec     = 'ui'; % up and in
Barrier         = 102;
AmericanOpt     = 0;
DividendType    = []; 
DividendAmounts = 0;
ExDividendDates = []; 

StockSpec       = stockspec(Sigma, AssetPrice, DividendType, ...
                  DividendAmounts, ExDividendDates);
RateSpec        = intenvset('Rates', 0.05, 'StartDates', '01-Jan-2003', ...
                  'EndDates', '01-Jan-2007', 'Compounding', -1);

ValuationDate   = '1-Jan-2003';
Maturity        = '01-Jan-2007';


TimeSpecCRR     = crrtimespec(ValuationDate, Maturity, 100);
CRRTree         = crrtree(StockSpec, RateSpec, TimeSpecCRR);
PriceCRR        = barrierbycrr(CRRTree, OptSpec, Strike, Settle, ...
                  ExerciseDates, AmericanOpt, BarrierSpec, Barrier)


TimeSpecEQP     = eqptimespec(ValuationDate, Maturity, 100);
EQPTree         = eqptree(StockSpec, RateSpec, TimeSpecEQP);
PriceEQP        = barrierbyeqp(EQPTree, OptSpec, Strike, Settle, ...
                  ExerciseDates, AmericanOpt, BarrierSpec, Barrier)
```

Output (in Matlab 2012b):

```
PriceCRR = 

   16.4225

PriceEQP = 

   16.4397
```

Answer (score 0):

I implement the down and out, but I'm still thinking how to implement up and in, paste the first section at first.

```
    function Aerican_Down_and_Out_Call = DownandOut(K,T,S,sig,r,H,N)

        dt = T/N;
        nu = r-0.5*sig^2;
        dxu = sqrt(sig^2*dt+(nu*dt)^2);
        dxd = -dxu;
        pu = 1/2+1/2*(nu*dt/dxu);
        pd = 1-pu;
        %precompute constants
        disc = exp(-r*dt);
        dpu = disc*pu;
        dpd = disc*pd;
        edxud = exp(dxu-dxd);
        edxd = exp(dxd);

        St = zeros(N+1,1);
        C  = zeros(N+1,1);
        St(1)=S*exp(N*dxd);
        for j=2:N+1 St(j) = St(j-1)*edxud;end
        for j=1:N+1
            if(St(j)>H) 
                C(j) = max(0,St(j)-K);    
            else
                C(j) = 0;
            end    
        end
        for i = N:-1:1
            for j = 1:i
                St(j)=St(j)/edxd;
                if(St(j)>H)
                    C(j)=dpd*C(j)+dpu*C(j+1);
                    C(j)=max(C(j),St(j)-K);
                else
                    C(j)=0;
                end
            end
        end
        Aerican_Down_and_Out_Call =C(1);
end
```